# numpy array using python's long type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy array with type `long` (that is, Python's `long`, not numpy's `long = int64`).

If I do:

```
m = np.eye(6, dtype=long)
print(m.dtype)
```

This outputs `int64`; i.e., they are not Python `long`s.

Is there any way to create a numpy array with each element being of type `long`?  Or is this some fixed-width versus non-fixed-width problem that numpy doesn't support?  If so, is there any library (preferably with a nice C API like numpy's) that can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python's long integer type is not a native numpy type, so you will have to
use the `object` data type.  The elements of an numpy array with `object` type can be any python objects.

For example,

```
In [1]: x = np.array([1L, 2L, 3L], dtype=object)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([1L, 2L, 3L], dtype=object)

In [3]: x[0]
Out[3]: 1L

In [4]: type(x[0])
Out[4]: long
```

Whether or not this is useful for you depends on what you want to do with the array of longs.