# Strange values calculating Fibonacci in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've got this small (maybe inefficient, but still reasonable) code:

```
fib = np.array([0,1])
for i in range(2,100):
    fib = np.append(fib, fib[-2] + fib[-1])
```

Reviewing the result at first all looks good:

```
In [17]: fib[:20]
Out[17]: array([   0,    1,    1,    2,    3,    5,    8,   13,   21,   34,   55,
         89,  144,  233,  377,  610,  987, 1597, 2584, 4181])
```

But then it becomes strange:

```
In [18]: fib[51:60]
Out[18]: 
array([-1109825406, -1408458269,  1776683621,   368225352,  2144908973,
       -1781832971,   363076002, -1418756969, -1055680967])
```

I figure this is a data type accuracy issue, but a clear explanation will be appreciated. Is there a way to do better?

Comment: looks like integer overflow.

Comment: Looks like an integer overflow. Not sure if there's a unbounded integer type in `numpy`, but, IIRC, Python's built-in `long` type is more flexible, assuming a non-`numpy` solution is acceptable.

Comment: So I guess fib = np.array([0.0,1.0],dtype=int64) or float is better. "long" gives same as the default int32.

Comment: @Theguy Depends what you want to do with the array afterwards. Floats are usually a bad idea if you care about precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figure this is a data type accuracy issue, but a clear explanation will be appreciated.

It seems that `numpy` arrays, by default, use signed 32-bit integers, which are only capable of storing values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. Once you exceed the maximum value, the numbers start to 'wrap around' to negative values. See the WP article on [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) for a better description.

> Is there a way to do better?

You could switch to using a 64-bit integer, which is fine for the example you gave...

```
>>> fib = np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.int64)
>>> for i in range(2,100): fib = np.append(fib, fib[-2] + fib[-1])
...
>>> fib[51:60]
array([ 20365011074,  32951280099,  53316291173,  86267571272,
       139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041])
```

...but fails towards the end of the array...

```
>>> fib[91:100]
array([ 4660046610375530309,  7540113804746346429, -6246583658587674878,
        1293530146158671551, -4953053512429003327, -3659523366270331776,
       -8612576878699335103,  6174643828739884737, -2437933049959450366])
```

It's [also possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664065/numpy-array-using-pythons-long-type) to use Python longs in `numpy` if you want to...

```
>>> fib = np.array([0, 1], dtype=object)
>>> for i in range(2,100): fib = np.append(fib, fib[-2] + fib[-1])
...
>>> fib[51:60]
array([20365011074L, 32951280099L, 53316291173L, 86267571272L,
       139583862445L, 225851433717L, 365435296162L, 591286729879L,
       956722026041L], dtype=object)
```

...which allows for unbounded integer values...

```
>>> fib[91:100]
array([4660046610375530309L, 7540113804746346429L, 12200160415121876738L,
       19740274219868223167L, 31940434634990099905L, 51680708854858323072L,
       83621143489848422977L, 135301852344706746049L,
       218922995834555169026L], dtype=object)
```

Note that you should only see the `L` suffix on the numbers if you're using Python v2.x rather than v3.x.

Comment: I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on the 0L.

Comment: Probably due to using Python 3. Try it without the `L`s.